# Why do we use memberless interface?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, interface

What is the point of writing an interface without members ?

[INamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx) is one example in .NET Framework. And it's described in MSDN as :

> Identifies a container control that
>   creates a new ID namespace within a
>   Page object's control hierarchy. This
>   is a marker interface only.

Is it used for just this kind of blocks :

```
if (myControl is INamingContainer)
{
    // do something
}
```

Or are there other advantages of it ?

**EDIT :** It was called [Marker Interface Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) (thanks Preet)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is to ensure that you can treat a collection of objects as the same type and then perform some operations on that type (You know that it must inherit from object).

Think of it like attributes. It's type meta data.

You also might want to perform an operation on a known type (e.g. System.Web.UI.Control) but only perform that operation if the type inherits from a certain interface (e.g. INamingContainer).

```
foreach(var ctrl in this.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is INamingContainer)
    {
        // Do something on the control
    }
}
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, this is how I apply "attributes" in C++, since you don't have reflection but you do have RTTI.

Comment: excellent point - not having done c++ for nearly 8 years I forget about things like this.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an answer the question. He asked about memberless interfaces -- ones that have no common operations or properties. It got accepted, tho...

Comment: The interface doesn't have a common operation but you still might perform a common operation *ON* types of that interface.

Answer (score 10):

Memberless interfaces are used to provide mixin-like capabilities in C#. So given a class A:

```
class A : B { ... }
```

You can give it extra functionality (a-la multiple inheritance) by defining an interface IStuff:

```
interface IStuff {}
```

then 'implementing' it in A:

```
class A : B, IStuff { ... }
```

and then adding the extra features

```
class Methods {
  public static void Something(this IStuff stuff) {
    // some functionality here
  }
}
```

Comment: _very_ nice thought. Hadn't seen this possibility before, but will now look for opportunities.

Comment: I don't understand how this is useful. If that extension method is not generic there's little you can do with it without casting. If you make it generic you don't need the empty interface.

Answer (score 8):

Its a marker interface. It can be used to decorate types so that you can find out it the type is correct at run time with out using reflection. we use it to ensure that generic types are correct in the callee.

Answer (score 3):

To confuse pythonistas who think duck typing is cool.